# How to make this Google Sheets script dynamic?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I'm working in a script to paste a table on the same sheet,  in my code I'm only pasting the table on the row A18

```
function NewQuote() {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ss.getRange("A18").activate();
 ss.getRange('A1:F14').copyTo(ss.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
};
```

I want to make this value dynamic and pasting the table on the next available row.

Comment: _I want to make this value dynamic and pasting the table on the next available row_ It seems to be some ambiguity about which "value" is to be dynamic, would you please clarify this. Similarly, "the next available row" could mean many things. Would you please clarify your meaning/definition of this also.